# Low display resolution Ubuntu Gnome remix 12.10

Tags: gnome-shell, ssd, ubuntu, gdm3

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome remix 12.10 and it can't recognize my display. My HW is:

Intel i3 3225 with HD 4000 onboard

/ is on a OCZ Vertex 4 SSD

display is an old IBM Thinkvision with vga connector connected through an adapter to dvi slot.

When I start it up I get to gdm which is in low resolution, then I log in the desktop is in low resolution as well. The display can't be recognized. I succeeded in changing the resolution with `xrandr` in `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` but am not really comfortable with this workaround.

I've red something about a race condition but that was more a LightDM thing and switching to GDM should help.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Consider inspecting the xorg logs, most likely `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` look for `EE` entries indicating any problem that may lead to clues to a more appropriate solution.

If nothing is found, you could create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`, or edit the equivalent sections on `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, this is the old fashioned way of configuring the display.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier             "monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier             "gpu0"
    Driver                 "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier             "screen0" 
    Device                 "gpu0"
    Monitor                "monitor0"
    DefaultDepth            24
    SubSection             "Display"
        Depth               24
        Modes              "1600x900" "1280x720" #Choose the resolution
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

You can change, add or remove the resolutions you want, even add the refresh rate like "1920x1080_60.0".

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. I commented out the `XRANDR` part from `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`, checked the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and couldn't find any errors.

Comment: For some reason it didn't save my whole answer so thanks a lot again. As i wrote I chcecked the log but no errors there. I couldn't find the `xorg.conf` in `etc/X11` neither this folder `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. However I was able to find `usr/sharte/X11/xorg.conf.d` but adding the file `10-monitor.conf` with sugested configuration (I changed it in accordence with my monitors parameters) didn't help. Is my install wrong? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You can create the file if it isn't present, at /etc/X11/